Celigo Google Sheets API Import Append Overwriting Data
I have a netsuite -> google sheets import that is made through Celigo that is set to append data to a google sheets. The HTTP method is set to post, and it is using the append method with valueInputOption = USER_ENTERED.
When the page size is set to 500, and I am watching the sheet, it is writing the first page to the sheet correctly, then overwriting the data until a 'version' (can be seen in the sheets version history) is created, then it appends data the data in row 501, and begins overwriting the data in row 501 until a new version is created, then appends the data in row 1001, and so on and so forth. This results in inconsistent data in the sheet and records being lost. I cannot increase the page size to input all of the data in one request because there is too much data, however there is not too much data for the sheet to handle, it is about 25000 rows and 9 columns.
My theory is that the write requests are coming in faster than the versioning can keep up with, so when the second request comes in it is not registered that there is data in the cell until a version is created. Does anyone have experience with this, or can confirm that my suspicions are correct in this case? If they are correct, what would the solution be to workaround this?
I tried increasing the page size to 15000. This made it so that the time in between write requests was long enough that it appended properly. What is unreliable about this, is that if there are only 15500, the first request would take quite a while but the second request would be quite fast, so it would again overwrite with the second request.
